# Access SQL Calculation in SELECT make not null

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that filters results for products which have had orders sent after an user-input date, and calculates what the quantity becomes if the order was sent after that date.

```
SELECT id, ProductName,
   [OnHand]+ SUM([OrderJoin.Quantity]) AS Qty After
FROM Query3
WHERE Query3.ShippedDate > [Enter End Date] And
  Query3.ShippedDate) Is Not Null
GROUP BY id, ProductName, OnHand;
```

But if I were to remove the WHERE statement, how would I make it so the Qty After would show as OnHand for the results that become NULL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `NZ()` to convert the `NULL` value to `0`.  Something like this:

```
SELECT id, ProductName,
       NZ(OnHand, 0) + NZ(SUM([OrderJoin.Quantity]), 0) AS QtyAfter
...
```